# How does this C code print the correct String?

Tags: c

The code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct island{
    char *name;
    struct island *previous;
} island;

void printIsland(island is){
    printf("%s\n", is.name);
    if(is.previous != NULL){
        printf("Previous island: %s", *(is.previous));
    }
}

int main(){

    // the file to be read.
    FILE *islandsFile = fopen("islands.txt","r");

    // temporary location to store the name read from the file.
    char name[40];

    // temporary pointer to an island which has been already read for linking.
    island *previousIsland = NULL;

    while(fscanf(islandsFile,"%s",name) != EOF){
        // allocate space for a new island and point to it with (*newIsland) pointer
        island *newIsland =malloc(sizeof(island));

        // assign name
        newIsland->name = strdup(name);
        newIsland->previous = previousIsland;
        // now previousIsland is the newIsland..
        previousIsland = newIsland;
        printIsland(*newIsland);
        puts("");
    }

    fclose(islandsFile);
}
```

the file is something like this:

```
islandone
islandtwo
islandthree
```

And the output will be:

```
islandone
islandtwo
Previous island: islandone
islandthree
Previous island: islandtwo
```

But why is

```
printf("Previous island: %s", *(is.previous))
```

printing the island name? You may as well what I would expect it to print, I do not know because I accidentally tried it really. How can it print the name of the island?

Comment: Compile with warnings (`-Wall -pedantic`) and GCC will put a stop to this.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's because `char *name` is the first member of the `struct island`, and so a pointer to an `island` will point to its `name` in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A struct is guaranteed to be laid out in memory with no padding before its first element. This means e.g. that a pointer to the struct, and a pointer to the first element of the struct, are the same thing.

`printf` doesn't have any ability to actually check what you pass to it, but takes on faith that the description in the format string is an accurate representation of the argument list (NB. a good compiler will add the check anyway). So `printf` assumes that the argument it's receiving is a `char *` and interprets it accordingly.

Because the argument you actually passed was a struct with a `char*` in the leading position, the data in that argument slot was identical to the data that *would* have been in that argument slot, if you had passed just the member instead of the whole struct.

The fact that that data was also followed by the rest of the struct doesn't affect anything in this case because - *only* because - `printf` wasn't instructed by the format string to look for any more arguments. More data was indeed passed to it, and had there been more arguments expected by the string, the remaining members of the `island` would have got in the way and corrupted the argument list.

Doing this is not safe in general and you should really only rely on the struct first-element-layout rule when handling *pointers*, not structs passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

`*(is.previous)` is the struct itself. The struct is transferred to `printf` by value, i.e. copied onto stack. The first field of the struct is `name` pointer, that is just `char*` which `printf` simply takes. As `printf` is vararg, the caller cleans the stack after the call.

P.S. Although `*(is.previous)` accidentally worked, but the code must be changed to `is.previous->name`.